# Set sound only if no existing notifications present

Tags: android, android-notifications

So I've been searching how to find if there are any existing (ie, active) notifications from my app. I want to set sound on my next notifications ONLY if there are no existing (active) notifications from my app.

As far as I could see, there are two ways to do this. One is by having a NotificationsListenenerService (which seems like overkill). The other is by using getActiveNotifications (which is only available for API 23+).

What is a simple way to set the sound ONLY if there are no active notifications (for API 16/18 onwards)?

PS: Newbie (Long-time lurker/upvoter) here with minimum reputation. Please be kind.